# C# HttpClient returns 415 Unsupported media type on Patch request

Tags: c#, patch, asp.net-core-3.1, json-patch, http-status-code-415

We have a .netcore 3.1 ApiController with an endpoint listening for PATCH requests, and defined a Test Server that we're using for the Integration/API tests.

PATCH request sent with Postman works just fine, but requests sent via HttpClient inside the XUnit tests are failing with 415 Unsupported media type.

Postman Patch request:
No specific headers other than Bearer token and Content-Type: "application/json"

In the tests, we use WebApplicationFactory and it's factory.CreateClient() for our HttpClient.

It shouldn't be an issue with Json Serialization since I looked into the content through debugger and it seems to be serialized just fine.

Also, our POST methods work completely out of the box with this exact same code (replacing "PATCH" with "POST" etc)

Looking forward to some advices. Also if you need any more info, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Controller:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Edit(Edit.Command request)
{
     return await Mediator.Send(request);
}
```

Command:

```
public class Command : IRequest
{
      public string Id { get; set; }

      public JsonPatchDocument<ObjectDTO> PatchDocument { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
[InlineData(/* inline data goes here */)]
public async void TestEdit_Ok(/* required parameters for the test */)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    /* create patch document logic goes here */

    var command = new Command()
    {
          Id = target,
          PatchDocument = patchDocument,
    };

    _testHelper.AddJsonContent(request, command);

    // Act
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Where helper method *AddJsonContent* is defined as:

```
public void AddJsonContent(HttpRequestMessage request, object content)
{
      request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      string serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
      request.Content = new StringContent(serializedContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

Comment: How do you configure `WebApplicationFactory`? Do you use a `Startup`? What does it do? `WebApplicationFactory` may not be configured to handle `PATCH` by default

Comment: You are not specifying the Content-Type that the server is accepting. With a Post and Patch you should specify the media type of request being sent from the client to the server. You are only specifying the accept which is what the client expects from the response. I think by default Postman is sending application/json. But try to do it programmatically in the same way you are adding the Accept add Content-Type and let me know

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
var patchResponse = await _client.PatchAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(serializedItemToUpdate,
                    Encoding.Unicode, "application/json-patch+json"));
```

in constructor, i use basic auth but i u can use other.

```
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _client = _factory.GetAnonymousClient();
            var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"user:pass");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));
        }
```

GetAnonymousClient()

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;

 public HttpClient GetAnonymousClient()
        {
            return CreateClient();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to say that, while I see this is a confirmed bug, I think once we used full url `http://localhost:PORT/endpoint` in the client instead of just `/endpoint`, we didn't encounter this issue anymore. This is the same as one of the proposed workarounds on github issue.

I see the ticket Vadim linked is still open so this may fix the issue for some of you.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is confirmed in Asp.Net Core 5.0
(the problem confirmed by me — I have the same problem as the topic starter)

The PATCH method returns the "415 Unsupported Media Type" status, when using the xUnit with WebApplicationFactory and factory.CreateClient() for HttpClient.

All possible attempts in different combinations results the 415 status.

However, other means like Swagger and Postman work well with the PATCH methods.

Only the xUnit (or WebApplicationFactory) PATCH method fails.

Finally, to conduct the testing, we made a workaround with POST methods, which contain `/with-partial-update` as a route part.

[This bug is reported to aspnetcore repository](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35770)

Comment: Confirmed where? Is there a link to a Github issue? XUnit knows nothing about HTTP. `WebApplicationFactory` isn't part of XUnit, it's an ASP.NET Core class used for integration testing to fake a web server. Swagger and Postman have nothing to do with it, they are clients that call real servers.

Comment: How would it be a problem with ASP.NET if changing client does that. Isn't that a problem with xUnit rather? You don't link to any credible sources.

Comment: @TanveerBadar WebApplicationFactory is an ASP.NET Core class used to [fake a web server for integration testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0). It's possible there is a bug there, or perhaps it's just not configured properly.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, the problem confirmed by me — I have the same problem as the topic starter. I also changed "using the xUnit WebApplicationFactory" with "using the xUnit with WebApplicationFactory". Could please advise where to report this problem?

Comment: At [ASP.NET Core's Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore). If you search for the word `WebApplicationFactory` you'll see there are tests for `HttpMethod.Get` and `HttpMethod.Delete` but searching for `WebApplicationFactory PATCH` returns nothing. It's possible this was never tested. The actual full exception text will be useful. Are you using just PATCH or Json Patch? Json Patch requires Json.NET, so *maybe* the test `Startup` is missing `services.AddNewtonsoftJson()` or maybe the test server didn't pick it up

Comment: If you open an issue you'll have to provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Which is something you should do here as well.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, ok just reported: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35770